# Moving Content to a New Domain Name and Hosting Company

Tags: seo, google, ranking

I created a new domain name on a new hosting company, I want to copy the content from my old website/hosting to the new website/hosting.

But I worry Google would "think" that I am copying the content from another sites, so it would affect the ranking of my new website.

I heard that I can notify Google about this, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the old site to the new site - redirect it properly. You might see changes on the rankings (if it already ranked) but it should get back on track as long as the redirects are properly set. Make sure everything's properly optimized on page too.

Comment: After the redirection is made, how long to keep the old website alive?

Comment: Most webmasters recommend for at least a year - just to give Google ample time to recognize the redirection. Read this https://www.highervisibility.com/blog/how-long-keep-301-redirect-before-removing/. It's a good point.

Comment: After I set up the 301 redirect, do I need to remove the content files from the old site?

Comment: Also, I heard that 301 redirect is cacheable, does it mean the redirect will be working forever even after I removed the old site?

Comment: Just keep the old site especially if there are lots of high-quality links pointing to it. You don't have to work on the old site but keep the domain alive and the 301 redirection working. You work on your new site.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using redirects in an htaccess file. This is something the Google bots understand perfectly. I am not an expert on this, so I'll direct you to a page addressing this issue, and you can do searches from there:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/301-permanent-redirect/289751/4

Comment: How long do I need to keep the redirection (old website) alive before removing everything completely?

Comment: You got the answer in the other comment.

Comment: After I set up the 301 redirect, do I need to remove the html files from the old site?